# How to find records whose date-ranges and value-ranges both overlap?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, data-structures, intervals

I'm reading records from a large CSV file, and I need to raise an error when the record that I'm reading conflicts with a record that I've already read.

The records contain a date-range and a value-range, where the values are strings; one record "conflicts" with another if their date-ranges and value-ranges both overlap. to check overlap natural ordering is considered. For example, these two records conflict:

| startDate | endDate | beginValue | endValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-05 | 2023-07-05 | 30abc | 41a |
| 2023-06-05 | 2023-08-05 | 40abc | 45z |

In the given example date ranges overlap and also the value ranges overlap as per string comparison, so this is conflicting. A record has to have both date and value overlap both with same record to be considered as overlap. There is no need to see the order of the records, just need to find if the overlap is present.
Consider this example:

| startDate | endDate | beginValue | endValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-05 | 2023-07-05 | 30abc | 41a |
| 2023-06-05 | 2023-08-05 | 41bc | 45z |
| 2023-09-05 | 2023-10-05 | 30abc | 41a |

in this example:

1. 1st and 2nd record overlap only for date range but not value range so they do not overlap.
2. 1st and 3rd record only overlap for values but not date range so they do not overlap.
   so this is non-conflicting

The problem is that the file contains millions of records, so I can't check them one-by-one.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you doing this all in memory within Java? Or are you trying to ask about databases?

Comment: How do your "overlap" `30abc | 40abc` and `41a | 45z`?

Comment: in this given example, only the dates overlap not the values. so they aren't considered overlapping

Comment: @BasilBourque the OP said that the sample values do not overlap. Nonetheless, I could not ascertain what does constitute overlapping values.

Comment: Can you just solve the two overlapping problems separately?

Comment: @ruakh your edit completely changed the meaning of the sample data. How do you know that the sample values overlap when the OP stated that they do not?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622016/efficient-way-to-find-overlapping-of-n-rectangles. That one's a bit different, firstly in that there are *two* lists of records (with the goal being to find records from one list that conflict with records from the other), and secondly in that the values are all numeric (so some answers use a numeric computing library); but you may be able to make use of the accepted answer there.

Comment: @Abra: The OP initially gave a *non*-conflicting example, which confused Basil Bourque (see comments above). So as part of my general rewrite for clarity, I changed it to a conflicting example. Unfortunately, the OP seems not to have noticed that I changed the example; so (s)he changed it to say that the conflicting example is actually non-conflicting. I just rolled that back. (Prateek Maurya, please speak up if I've misunderstood.)

Comment: @PrateekMaurya: If two records conflict, is it a firm requirement that you have to retain the one you encounter first and reject the one you encounter second? I ask because there's a very straightforward approach that you can use if you don't care which one is retained and which one is rejected.

Comment: @ruak Actually, I was not confused by the example. I am confused because we have no definition of what it means for digits-with-text to be "overlapping". Overlapping of date ranges is obvious (except for the minor detail of Half-Open versus Fully-Open), but overlapping of arbitrary digits-with-text is not all obvious.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Given that the OP talked of storing those values in a TreeSet in order to find lower bounds of intervals, it seems clear that (s)he's using some ordering — very likely the natural ordering — and the intervals (a, b) and (c, d) "overlap" if a < d and b > c. No?